# Can I access the NHibernate ISession instance from IQueryable?

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I'm trying to wrap up a few complicated query patterns into extension methods on `IQueryable<Foo>` and have occasional need to do some outer joins in them.

```
static IQueryable<Foo> Filter(this IQueryable<Foo> foos, params string[] searchTerms)
{
    //...
    return from t in session.Query<Tags>()
           from f in foos
           where
               (t.Name.Contains (searchTerms[0] && f.Tags.Contains(t))
               || f.Name.Contains(searchTerms[0]
           select f;
}
```

Another case also requires the session access to do some save operations (yes, yes, side effects are bad. It's for tracking query patterns).

I've worked around this in the first case by passing in the collection of tags as an argument, which, while a bit ugly for the caller, works fine, but obviously doesn't scale, and the only other option I've been able to divine for figuring this out for the general case is to just pass the `ISession` in directly.

What I would love is to have some helper method like the following that I could call from the extension method:

```
static ISession GetSession<T> (IQueryable<T> query)
{
    // do magic
}
```

Even if it involves downcasting the queryable, or the query provider or something to Nh* I think I would prefer it to passing the session in. But I haven't found a way to access this (the session property on `NhQueryProvider` is protected). Am I missing some other way to get this out of the expression?

Comment: I think the only option you've got is accessing the Session property by reflection. Personally, I'd rather pass the session then rely on a hack though.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely preferable to reflecting on it. Just was hoping there was some other way to grab it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use reflection:

```
IQueryable<Product> query = Session.Query<Product>();
ISession session = query.Provider.GetType().GetProperty("Session", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(query.Provider, null) as ISession;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may benefit from using the [QueryObject pattern](http://coderkarl.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/the-query-object-pattern-2/)-
You'll define a method that takes an `ISession` parameter and invokes the query on it;
You can define the different search terms using properties of your query object instead of resorting to the string array solution.

Ayende has a little [cooler flavour](http://ayende.com/blog/2266/query-objects-vs-methods-on-the-repository)

Comment: Don't understand how this would help me avoid a string array (or indeed, why I'd want to). I have a variable-length list of terms that I want to get a disjunctive set of matches on.